# Did Apple screw up CarPlay in the 17.1.1/17.1.2 software update?

Tags: ios, software-update, car-integration

### The background:

I got an automatic iOS update (to 17.1.1 last night)

This morning I plugged my phone into a USB-C to USB-A cable plugged into my Honda Civic's data port, expecting it to fire up CarPlay so I could listen to some music as I ran my errands.

### The problem:

Instead, I got repeated messages that said:

> A charging error has occurred with the connected USB device. When safe please check the compatibility of the device and USB cable and try again.

(That text is transcribed from a photo of the cars display using the text recognition feature built into iOS 17, which is kinda cool, but irrelevant to this thread...)

I tried repeatedly to disconnect and reconnect the phone. I tried a USB-C cable with a USB-C to USB-A adapter on the end. I tried to get it to pair wirelessly. No joy. I tried forgetting my phone in the Civic's settings menu. Now it doesn't let me get to CarPlay at all.

I am quite suspicious that the OS update is what caused the problem. I googled around and saw other people reporting similar problems with various iOS 17.x subversions, but nothing to the effect of "The 17.1.1 update broke CarPlay on my car."

Are any of you aware of such a problem? I see there is another update, 17.1.2, scheduled for tonight, but I did see one person say they had this problem and 17.1.2 didn't fix it, so I don't hold high hopes.

Comment: found this https://www.wesleychapelhonda.com/honda-info/honda-apple-carplay/

Comment: @Ruskes thanks for the link but I don't see anything beyond general help there. ("Have you tried turning it off and back on again?")

Comment: check the troubleshoot section

Comment: I have an iPhone 11 Pro running 17.1.2. I have not had any issues with Carplay with iOS 17. There are also no mentions of updates to CarPlay with either iOS updates. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213781

Have you tried to reboot your iPhone and then connecting to your car?

Comment: @ErniePC12 Thanks for the reply, and I'm glad your phone is behaving itself. It could be a change to USB-C PD (power delivery) on the phone that's screwing up Hondas. (It might actually be a bug in Honda's handling of USB-C PD power handshaking, and Apple's update exposes the bug.)

Comment: @DuncanC Given that my 2018 Fit's headhunt runs a version of Android from 2012, it would surprise me if there are issues with Honda.

Comment: @ErniePC12, my suspicion is that something in Apple's most recent OS update exposes a problem specific to the iOS/Honda combination.